# Proving a function given another property is true

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$. I'm trying to prove that $f(0) = 0$. It seems like a fairly basic problem, but I don't quite understand the intuition behind it. If anyone could shed some light on this I'd be grateful.

Comment: Just set $x = y = 0$ and observe that $f(0) = f(0) + f(0)$ cancellation implies $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Gregory I made this problem so much harder than it had to be lol. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$

Let $y=0$
$\implies \;$ $f(x+0) = f(x) + f(0)$ $\; \Longleftrightarrow \;$ $0 = f(0)$.